# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, ..' The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: linq-to-sql, assemblies

Im bit lost here, I was developing some project for a while, in the beginning I was using console application to execute scripts, then I start building Silveilght and Web applications. Lately I had need to run some of that scripts again and I cant run Console project with  reference to Data project, because once I'm trying to run console project I get this exception. Disregarding regarding Console project I need to run those scripts on daily basis via Windows Service, which have same problem as Console App...

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

But same assembly (data project) works fine with website/silverlight app.

I have absolutely no clue what this means and what to do..

I tried creating new console app or data project from scratch but it didn't worked..

I'm using LINQ TO SQL

Anybody can help me?

Comment: I had an issue like this the other day - is it possible that the project was developed on a 32-bit machine and is now being executed on a 64-bit machine (or vice-versa)?